# Why apply rgb2gray and normalize before normalized cross-correlation?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

```
function out = findWaldo(im, filter) 

% convert image (and filter) to grayscale
im_input = im;
im = rgb2gray(im);
im = double(im);
filter = rgb2gray(filter);
filter = double(filter);
filter = filter/sqrt(sum(sum(filter.^2)));
out = normxcorr2(filter, im);
```

Question1: Why we first do rgb2gray on im and filter?

Question2: What does the last second line actually do? Namely,

```
filter = filter/sqrt(sum(sum(filter.^2)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:** Why apply `rgb2gray` first?

`normxcorr2` standing for "Normalized 2-D cross-correlation" works on a 2D signal (see [doc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html)). A RGB image is a 3D signal: `width x height x color` (e.g. `1024 x 1024 x 3`, 3 since it's three colors). That is why you flatten it first to one color channel. Applying the filter to the image on each color separately would be the alternative, but then you also need to process three correlations (average them or something...).

**Question 2:** What does `filter = filter/sqrt(sum(sum(filter.^2)));`do?

It squares the filter image, then sums over rows and columns (basically all squared gray values of the filters) to get a single number that the squareroot is applied to and then is used to divide all filter image values.

I'd say it is some sort of normalization to handle specific input signals, maybe an attempt to get values from 0  - 1. But since *normalized* cross correlation ([`normxcorr2`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html)) does normalization itself, **this step is definitely not needed** for it. Unless you don't do something other than cross correlation with the filter variable, I'd consider this an artifact that **should be deleted**.

Comment: For question 2, could u explain a bit more details? Maybe it is some kind of formula, but I still don't understand why square the filter. What does this step do? And why sum twice.

Comment: @Gang: Sure, I can explain a bit - but I still think it is a unnecessary and weird step, so I can't explain WHY it is done here ;) Normalizing in general is done to get values in a specific range, e.g. to make them comparable. **Sum**: You sum twice because you have a 2D matrix: first sum over all columns, then over all rows. This will give you a single number. `sum(sum(A)) = sum(A(:))` for a 2D matrix (`A(:)` giving you all elements of matrix A).

Comment: **Square**: If you don't square, values cancel out (e.g. [-2 2] -> sum = 0). When you square that doesn't happen (e.g. (-2)² + 2² = 8). To undo the effect on the actual values (they increase), you usually take the squareroot. Since you sum here in between, that doesn't really work and makes it a weird normalization imo.

Comment: _**BUT**_: Like both Ibezito and I concluded normalizing is done by `normxcorr2`, hence this line effectively does nothing, because `normxcorr2` will undo what it does - it will normalize `im` and `filter` to a common range before correlating. In fact if you input two images with RGB values from 0-255 and you apply this line to `filter` only (which will give values between 0 and some value probably much smaller than 1), you will increase the work `normxcorr2` has to do, since it will now have to convert one image to the range of the other. I'd go as far as: **It _should_ be deleted/ignored.**

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps me understand better.

Answer (score 1):

**General explanation of the function**

This function receives two inputs: an image file and a template.
For example, the image file may be a large scene of findings Waldo game and the template can be a picture of Waldo himself.
The output is a matrix called 'out' with same size as the image file. s.t. each pixel holds a "matching results". The higher the value - the higher the chances that the patch centered around the pixel holds a similar pattern such as the template.
The maximal value should be on the pixel in which Waldo is.

**Question 1**

[rgb2gray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) function receives an rgb image with 3 channels and transorm it into gray image.
It is done on im and on filter because normxcorr2 function only works with grayscale images.

**Question 2**

The last perform normalization of the pattern: it divides it by it's norm, thus changing it to 1. **In fact, this line is not required and should be deleted**. Normalization stage is already performed inside [normxcorr2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html) function.

Comment: Regarding Question 2 I was wondering the same thing, but it doesn't actually change the norm to 1 but to values from `0` to `max(filter) / sqrt(sum(sum(filter.^2)))` which isn't a specific norm I know of. Doing `(filter - min(filter)) / max(filter)` would norm to 1, isn't it?

Comment: @Honeybear It normalizes the pattern in the sense that its 2-norm is changed to 1. (i.e. sqrt(sum(sum(filter.^2))) will be 1 after the change).
Subtracting the min value and dividing by max will change each pixel to be between 0 to 1. I agree that the second approach makes more sense. 
However, either way, this stage is not required. The normalization stage is done inside normxcorr2 function. This function already performs centering and normalization (by definition of normalized cross correlation)

Comment: Aye okay, thanks for explanation! Didn't know the term "2-norm".